# How to create an application that reads an XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, excel, html

I want to create an application that reads an XML file instead manually opening it with Excel.

Currently, I open the file manually with Excel, add a filter "money" and sum up the total amount.

I want to create an application where I click on a button that parses the XML file, automatically filters "money" to sum the amounts and returns the total.

Comment: Nobody is going to give you the entire code. Your goal is made up of sections (opening xml, parsing xml, displaying output etc..). Research on each part - there are plenty of examples on the net.

Comment: I dont want the code. I want to know where to start. I am very new at this.

Comment: Where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

i think in this case it is way easier to create an excel macro. there is no need to write a program.

how to write and enable macros in excel:
http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html